# Opening Office 2007 files using a Vista or Win7 client on a server 2008 file share causes lockups and explorer crashes

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office

I think this mostly happens when trying to open files opened by other users. In the XP/2003 days you would get some kind of warning about a locked/read only file. With 7/Vista/2008 I'm just seeing clients hang (Word just sits there) and if I go into the file share and attempt to right-click on the file, explorer hangs for several minutes.

I tried disabling AV on the file server as well as locally.  No luck.

I've read that SMB2.0 might be the culprit here, but even testing that solution means disabling it on both the client and server, and requires a server reboot.  Does this sound like an SMB2 issue?

The server is 2008 SP1. The clients are Win7 vanilla and Vista SP2 with all the current updates. Office 2007 SP2 with all updates.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to just disable SMB2 on the server and reboot any machine that was still connected to it.  Disabling caching helped (I think) but the real issue is SMB2.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with Vista\7 clients accessing files on W2K8 shares. Here's what I would look at:

On the shares where the files reside see if offline file caching is enabled. If it is, disable it.

Once I did that the lockups ceased to happen.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Do you know if this was resolved in SP2 for 2008?

Comment: No, I don't know.